# Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when trying to clear out a named range

Tags: excel, vba

Brand new to VBA and still tying to figure out how workbooks/sheets function internally.
My goal here is to be able to clear out everything that's in a dynamic named range.
The scope of the named range is the workbook.
My current code:

```
Dim inital As Worksheet
Set inital = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LeadTimes")
inital.Range("SearchResultsV5").ClearContents
```

There is a lot to my program and its kind of messy so I am trying not to have to dump everything but if more context is needed that can be added.

Note: There is only one workbook and two sheets Sheet1(Database), Sheet2(Leadtimes) I am trying to clear out the named range on sheet2. As well the named range is called SearchResultsv5 and refers to `=OFFSET(LeadTimes!$A$9,0,0,COUNTA(LeadTimes!$A:$A)-1,5)`

It came to my attention that the named range uses `=OFFSET` which is actually a formula, I tried using the `.evaluate` to no avail. As well I forgot to mention that I know the range is correct as I have successfully cleared out the the whole range using `Sheets("LeadTimes").Range("SearchResultsV5").ClearContents`  I realized that although it worked it was inside some if statements and loops that I didn't want it to be, when I tried to take that exact code and put it at the top of the sub routine, so it would execute immediately I also got the error `'Object required'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11870317/9245853

Comment: You don't have to record your edits with *EDIT1*. The [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67326302/revisions) takes care of tracking changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive reading of the VBA documentation I figured out that I wasn't properly defining  the Worksheets.
Updated Working code:

```
Worksheets("LeadTimes").Range("SearchResultsV5").ClearContents
```